# Fibonacci with Generators

Tags: python, generator, fibonacci

I am trying to make the Fibonacci Succession with Generators but my code return 2**a...

```py
def fibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a = b
        b = a + b
n = int(input("How long? "))
fib = fibonacci()

for i in range(n):
    print(next(fib))
```

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is that when you assign `b = a + b`, you've already updated the value of `a` to be the old value of `b`. Thus you are effectively assigning `b = b + b` or `2*b`, which is why you get `0, 1, 2, 4, 8, ...` as a result. You can work around that by assigning `a` and `b` at the same time:

```py
def fibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

fib=fibonacci()

for i in range(10):
    print(next(fib))
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```